# MySQL and ORACLE performance - SELECT + retrieve rows + DELETE vs. DELETE WHERE SELECT FROM

Tags: mysql, performance, oracle

I am going through some performance improvements of current application I am working on and I was thinking which of the next scenarios are better in performance (consider good server hardware, or forget about the hardware at all).

Consider You need to do an `update`, `insert` or `delete` with particular information needed to be fetched from other table(s). Which scenario would have better performance?

**EDIT**: since the performance question in this case is *highly (platform|vendor)-specific*, I am curious more about **MySQL** and **ORACLE** DBMS...

**1. Making the job done by only SQL**
e.g. (all queries are only hypothetical):

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (
    val1,
    val2,
    val3,
    (SELECT col3 FROM table2 WHERE col1 = [some_variable] LIMIT 1),
    val5
)
```

or

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col5 FROM table2 WHERE col1 = [some_variable])
```

or

```
UPDATE table1 SET col4 = (SELECT col3 FROM table2 WHERE col1 = [var1] LIMIT 1) WHERE col1 = [var2]
```

against

**2. Splitting the logic into two parts** with `SELECT` result set being retrieved by the application and performing simple `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` afterwards.

e.g. (I'm using some pseudo-code):

```
def ids_to_delete = fetch('SELECT col5 FROM table2 WHERE col1 = [some_variable]')
execute('DELETE FROM table 1 WHERE col1 IN(' . implode(',', ids_to_delete) . ')')
```

or

```
for (var1 in vars)
    def val_to_insert = fetch('SELECT col5 FROM table2 WHERE col1 = [var1]' LIMIT 1)
    execute('INSERT INTO table 1 VALUES [varX.a], [varX.b], [varX.c], [val_to_insert], [varX.d]')
endfor
```

etc.

**Which one is better for performance?** I think the first approach should be faster, as there is only one link from application code to application database, though there are subqueries that may not act as fast. I am curious about the general performance without the concrete SQL implementation and without the concrete application environment (if possible).

Comment: What's your ideal measure of performance? Network utilisation? DBMS load? Total time taken to complete the operation?

Comment: Performance is **highly** platform-specific, and SQL is just the query language, used by many database system. You need to tell us what **concrete database** (and which version of it!) you're using - is it MySQL? Postgres? Oracle? IBM DB2? Interbase? SQL Server? What else?? Please update your tags accordingly!

Comment: @marc_s I thought this could be answered in general. What if I would ask what is better performance for MySQL, ORACLE, SQL Server, PostGres, DB2? Would You then mark my question as *too broad*?

Comment: As I already said: how exactly a particular database handles one SQL construct vs. another is highly platform- and vendor-specific, so I'm afraid this question cannot really be answered globally ....

Comment: @Tim To be honest, keeping all three criteria You have mentioned as low as possible or finding the best compromise between them should be considered as best performance... If the first approach keeps low network and total time but makes the DBMS load too high while the second approach makes the network and time only slightly higher while keeping low DBMS load, then it could be considered as better performance...

Comment: OK, I'll modify the question and let's say I am now focused at least on MySQL and ORACLE. Will it be not too broad though?

Comment: You'll need to check execution plans/explanations to be sure, but personally - I'd not do any of those. But would prefer #1. I'd do my best to combine them in one query to avoid sub queries because *generally* speaking - sub-queries are slow. Only *generally* speaking of course, as much SQL has the answer "depends" :)
But generally speaking - the more you can simplify a query/process, the better.

Comment: I'd challenge anyone here to come up with a DBMS+environment where the 2nd approach performs better for any metric than the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing the operation in the minimum number of SQL statements is almost always going to be the correct approach, not only for performance reasons but because the operation is guaranteed to be atomic and to have a single consistency point.